# Trying to process raw string (rank of countries by GDP) with python for other uses

Tags: python, data-processing

I'm pretty new to this so sorry if this is a dumb  question. 
I'm trying to sort some data. Here's a rank of countries by GDP for example, that I'd like to find percentages of, add up certain amounts top down (like a CDF), etc. How would I make a python script to go through the "spaces" and tabs. I'd like to also export it to an excel file.

```
1   European Union  $   15,970,000,000,000
2   United States   $   15,940,000,000,000
3   China   $   12,610,000,000,000
4   India   $    4,761,000,000,000
5   Japan   $    4,704,000,000,000
6   Germany $    3,250,000,000,000
7   Russia  $    2,555,000,000,000
8   Brazil  $    2,394,000,000,000
9   United Kingdom  $    2,375,000,000,000
10  France  $    2,291,000,000,000
11  Italy   $    1,863,000,000,000
12  Mexico  $    1,788,000,000,000
13  Korea, South    $    1,640,000,000,000
14  Canada  $    1,513,000,000,000
15  Spain   $    1,434,000,000,000
16  Indonesia   $    1,237,000,000,000
17  Turkey  $    1,142,000,000,000
18  Iran    $    1,016,000,000,000
19  Australia   $     986,700,000,000
20  Saudi Arabia    $     921,700,000,000
```

There are also variations in formatting?

Comment: Lots of separate things you want to do: which ones have you tried... and do you have some failed code to show? Otherwise, it sounds like you want us to do it all for you...

Comment: Yea, I'm sorry about that. I'll might just delete this question and come up with a better one.

Comment: Since this has no non-deleted answers - why not make this question a much more specific one with some aspect of what you're trying to do and what you've tried...?